# Wanting to switch and print the max and min in my two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, element

Hello I am creating an array that prints the array, the max and min of the array, and swaps the max and min of the array. I've coded the first two correctly however I am a bit lost for the switch method. I tried to code it similarly to how I got the max and mins of the array but I am not sure how I can switch it. I tried returning it like this `return switch max, min;` but I did not think that was correct I tried looking up a similar example to this but I couldn't really understand it? Could anyone explain what exactly I am doing wrong?

```
 public class mainClass {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] twoDArray= {{1,2,3},{4,6,5}};
    print(twoDArray);
    System.out.println(max(twoDArray));
    System.out.println(min(twoDArray));
    
}
public static int max(int[][] twoDArray) {
    int max=twoDArray[0][0];
    
    for (int row=0; row < twoDArray.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col < twoDArray[row].length; col++)
            if(twoDArray[row][col]>max) max=twoDArray[row][col];
    return max;
}

public static int min(int[][] twoDArray) {
    int min=twoDArray[0][0];
    
    for (int row=0; row < twoDArray.length; row++)
        for (int col=0; col < twoDArray[row].length; col++)
            if(twoDArray[row][col]<min) min=twoDArray[row][col];
    return min;
}

public static void switchMaxMin(int[][] twoDArray) {
    int min=twoDArray[0][0], max=twoDArray[0][0];   //int max, min;

    
    //int maxRow, maxCol, minRow, minCol
    
    for (int maxRow=0; maxRow < twoDArray.length; maxRow++) //when find a larger element, update max, maxRow, maxCol
        for (int maxCol=0; maxCol < twoDArray[maxRow].length; maxCol++)
            if(twoDArray[maxRow][maxCol]>max) max=twoDArray[maxRow][maxCol];
    
    for (int minRow=0; minRow < twoDArray.length; minRow++)//when find a smaller element, update min, minRow, minCol
        for (int minCol=0; minCol < twoDArray[minRow].length; minCol++)
            if(twoDArray[minRow][minCol]>min) min=twoDArray[minRow][minCol];
    //int maxRow, maxCol, minRow, minCol
    
    return switch MaxMin; //error??? I am not certain on the specific method to switch it 
    //switch
}
public static void print(int[][] twoDArray) {
    for (int row=0; row < twoDArray.length; row++) {
        for (int col=0; col < twoDArray[row].length; col++) {
            System.out.print(twoDArray[row][col]+"\t");
        }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Statement/expression `switch` has nothing to do with swapping elements in the array; also, the method is defined as `void` and cannot return anything;

You need to find the indexes of the `min` and `max` elements in the 2D array and then swap their contents like this:

```java
public static void switchMaxMin(int[][] twoDArray) {
    int min = min(twoDArray), max = max(twoDArray);
   
    int maxRow = -1, maxCol = -1, minRow = -1, minCol = -1;
    out:
    for (int i = 0; i < twoDArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < twoDArray[i].length; j++) {
            if (twoDArray[i][j] == max && maxRow == -1) {
                maxRow = i;
                maxCol = j;
            } else if (twoDArray[i][j] == min && minRow == -1) {
                minRow = i;
                minCol = j;
            }
            if (minRow != -1 && maxRow != -1) {
                break out;
            }
        }
    }
    arr[minRow][minCol] = max;
    arr[maxRow][maxCol] = min;
}
```

However, you may need to define additionally how to handle cases when there are *multiple* `min` and `max` elements in the input 2D array.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I also have one more question? How would I print the result of this code? I know I cannot return it since the method would be void. Would I have to pass the array through my print method at end? How would I modify it?

Comment: The array gets modified inside `switchMaxMin`, so you may just invoke your `print(twoDArray);` method _after_ invoking `switchMaxMin` and you'll see the difference.